# rspec// How can I get links url / How can I prevent selenium to open new window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara

I'm new to rspec capybara.

I have two question

1 . How can I get links url from link in the page?

Something like;

```
url = find('a', :text => 'Test link')['href']
pp url
=> "http://www.testweb.com"
```

2 . How can I prevent selenium to open new window of firefox after clicking link?

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
      dummy_data = page.find('a[href]')
      pp dummy_data['href']
      dummy_data_urls = dummy_data['href']
      pp "Visiting facebook"
      visit(dummy_data['href'])
```